# YouTube API - change H1 tag based on mouseover of API grabbed thumbnails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I'm working on a "latest videos" section for my website. I'm attempting to get it down on a test page before I move it to the homepage. I have an API call that grabs the info for my latest 3 uploads, and spits out their thumbnails. It also links the thumbnail to their appropriate video. What I want to do is then change the "Latest Videos" h1 tag to the title of the video when the thumbnail is moused over. How would I do that considering the following code? (I took out my playlist ID and API key from this example.)

```
<body>
<h1 id="mouse">Newest Videos</h1>
<div id="thumbnail">
    <a href="#" id="link1" target="new"><img id="thumb1" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /></a>
    <a href="#" id="link2" target="new"><img id="thumb2" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /></a>
    <a href="#" id="link3" target="new"><img id="thumb3" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /></a>
</div>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=OnLoadCallback"></script>
<script>
    $thumbnail = $('#thumbnail');
    $.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=3&playlistId=+{PlaylistID}&key={MyAPIKEY}', function ( data ) {
        $('#thumb1').attr('src', data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url);
        $('#link1').attr('href', 'https://youtube.com/watch?v='+data.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId);
        $('#thumb2').attr('src', data.items[1].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url);
        $('#link2').attr('href', 'https://youtube.com/watch?v='+data.items[1].snippet.resourceId.videoId);
        $('#thumb3').attr('src', data.items[2].snippet.thumbnails.medium.url);
        $('#link3').attr('href', 'https://youtube.com/watch?v='+data.items[2].snippet.resourceId.videoId);
    });
</script>
```

If the title of each video is located at data.items[#].snippet.title, how would I replace the text of the h1 tag on thumbnail mouseover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add something along these lines to your `.get` callback:

```
$('#link1').mouseover(function() { $('#mouse').text(data.items[0].snippet.title);});
```

and to revert back when the mouse moves off:

```
$('#link1').mouseout(function() { $('#mouse').text('Newest Videos');});
```

Comment: Okay, that's awesome! Thanks! Would chaining these through some if/else if statements allow me to have it revert back when the mouse isn't over anything?

Comment: Added `mouseout` code into the answer that would revert the text back to `Newest Videos` when the mouse moves off the link.